# Ember.js - Define ArrayProxy inside an Object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of categories. Each category can have sub categories.
This is the model I've created:

```
App.Category = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    subCategories: Em.ArrayProxy.create({content: []})
});
```

The problem is, if I push a sub category into the `subCategories` array, it is pushed into every instance of `App.Category`

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazyboy/HdcQj/).

I don't understand why this is happening, and how should I rewrite this to work properly.

---

**Code**:

```js
App.Category = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    subCategories: Em.ArrayProxy.create({content: []})
});

App.categories = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    // assumes list of categories is ordered by parent id
    loadCategories: function(cats) {
        for (var i=0, cat; i < cats.length; i++) {
            var parentID = cats[i].parentID;
            delete cats[i].parentID;
            cat = App.Category.create(cats[i]);

            if (parentID !== null) {
                var parent = this.findProperty('id', parentID);
                parent.get('subCategories').pushObject(cat);
            } else {
                this.pushObject(cat);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the hash passed to `extend` defines the properties on the prototype of the objects that are instantiated by the class. Whereas `create` define the properties on the instantiated object. There is a very good blog post by Dan Gebhardt about [Understanding Ember.js Object](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/). You should check it out.

Your problem can be solved as follows, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/hXHqs/:

```js
App.Category = Em.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('subCategories', Em.ArrayProxy.create({
            content: []
        }));
    }
});
```